# 'Running' Redis with Node

Tags: node.js, redis

Somewhat trivial question but I feel it would be crucial to get this answered. My question is about Redis and Node; how to 'run' a Redis db and have Node interact with it.

I plan to use node_redis (https://github.com/mranney/node_redis). I am fairly comfortable saying I understand how to use this module to interact with the Redis db.

My questions if one level higher: how and where is the Redis db 'running'? Do I have to install, create and then run/turn on this db **before** I am able to use node_redis to manipulate it? Or does the act of requiring node_redis already guarantee that there will be a Redis db to interact with?

Asking because my app will run on a device (not a machine) that I know can execute Node because has Node installed but I cannot install Redis on it (or at least I dont know how to) if Node will not be doing it for me.

WHEW I hope that was not too wordy. TIA!

Niko

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redis is a separate program. You have to [download it](http://redis.io/download), install, and run separately. If you'll accept default settings (listen port), `node_redis` with then connect to it automatically as, by default, redis installation has no passphrase set.

You'd just need to call:

```
var client = require("redis").createClient();
```

If your requirements are basic (and chances are they are, since you're running it in a limited environment), you might actually use different key-value store, like [nStore](https://github.com/creationix/nstore) which is implemented in JS and uses simple files as a storage. This would not require any other program than node itself.

Comment: thank you very much! your answer nailed my question on the head. I will look into nStore, I saw that while researching. More power to you